# NoScript has disabled Ublock's scripts

Tags: security, add-on, noscript

For some time now NoScript has disabled all Ublock's scripts. I have not this problem on Firefox.
The scripts only work when I put Tor on low level of security. Can I put it on high level and do this: Extensions -  add-ons Manager - and click on Disable NoScript - and then on "No, just stop blocking scripts"? Is it dangerous?

Ps: I need Ublock to block ads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug.
The new Tor Browser update has resolved the problem.